# Using a ListenableFuture Azure call inside an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, azure, asynchronous

I'm a bit new to Android, Java, and Azure, and I'm using the Azure MobileServiceClient class to try to call various APIs in my backend. The problem I'm having is that MobileServiceClient's methods all seem to be async, using ListenableFutures.

This would be just fine, except that I want to use these methods in a helper class that also does other stuff that ought to be async (so it extends AsyncTask). However, since the MobileServiceClient call is async, it causes the AsyncTask to return prematurely. I want the AsyncTask not to call its onPostExecute method until the MobileServiceClient method has returned.

How do I avoid this issue? Do I need to change my architecture? Is it possible to put a MobileServiceClient call inside another async task and have it block it?

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Doing background task");
    if(mTaskType==tTaskType.LOGIN_TASK){
        login();
        //do other stuff here that should be async
    }
    return true;
} 

private void login(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Doing login task...");
    ListenableFuture<JsonElement> result = mClient.invokeApi("login",    mJSONHelper.makeLoginObject(thisUser));
    Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
            error.setError(ErrorHelper.Error.NETWORK_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JsonElement result) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can refer to the link "Add authentication to your Mobile Services Android app" https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/.

Comment: login function need not be in another thread as azure calls are not blocking, u can continue all ur operations post success in onSuccess and faiures in onFailure..

Comment: Also as i know u can just call result.get(), this would block until result is complete.  ur code can continue just like a blocking call,sync way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to preface this with the caveat that I'm not very familiar with Android either.  However from my experience on other platforms and a quick search of the APIs this is the approach I think you should take.  I'm also not promising that code code snippets will compile as I haven't checked that, but they should be close to doing so.

Your `login` method should return a `ListenableFuture<T>` and then the `doInBackground` method can then add it's own callback which is executed when the login completes.

If you want something else to be able to wait for the `doInBackground` task to complete then that should also return a `ListenableFuture<T>` which can be done by using the `Futures.transform` method to chain together a series of async calls.

Here is what I think it should look like:

```
protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Doing background task");
    if(mTaskType==tTaskType.LOGIN_TASK){
        var loginFuture = ListenableFuture<UserDetail> login();

        Futures.addCallback(loginFuture, new FutureCallback<UserDetail>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UserDetail userDetail)
            {
                // do other stuff here that should be async
                // also optionally you could implement this as a transform
                // style thing to and return another future from this `doInBackground`
                // method so other parts of your code could know when it is completed.
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable exc) { 
                // I'd quite likely move the error handling from the login method here
                // as that way it can also handle any exceptions caused by the transform
                // from json to user detail as well. 
            }
        })
    }
} 

private ListenableFuture<UserDetail> login(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Doing login task...");
    ListenableFuture<JsonElement> loginFutureResult = mClient.invokeApi("login",    mJSONHelper.makeLoginObject(thisUser));
    Futures.addCallback(loginFutureResult, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
            // This is just to keep with what your style is, for recording the error
            // I think you might be better off handling it at a higher level and
            // also you might want to check `exc` to see if it was an actual network
            // error and not for example just failed credentials or something.
            error.setError(ErrorHelper.Error.NETWORK_ERROR);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JsonElement result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "The login was successful");
        }
    });

    // lets pretend that instead of returning the JSON response 
    // you wanted to map it to a user detail before returning, just to show how to do that.

    AsyncFunction<JsonElement, UserDetail> transformUserJsonFunction =
        new AsyncFunction<JsonElement, UserDetail>() {
            public ListenableFuture<UserDetail> apply(JsonElement userJson) {
                // some code to map the json element to user detail
                UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail(userJson);
                return Futures.immediateFuture(userDetail);
            }
        };


    return Futures.transform(loginFutureResult, transformUserJsonFunction);
}
```

I hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, this is definitely pointing me in the right direction. It looks like your code isn't using any of the async functionality provided by the AsyncTask class, is that right? If so, I should just stop extending AsyncTask and implement all my async behaviour via Futures?

Comment: I'd give it a try without the AsyncTask and see how that goes.  AsyncTask seems to be a way of writing a nice background task in a synchronous fashion and reporting the results back to the UI thread when it's done.

Comment: Since the Azure Mobile Services API is already doing the request asynchronously via the Future it might not make a log of sense to try and translate it over to the AyncTask style model.

Comment: I would however guess there is likely to be a way to wait synchronously for a future to complete (blocking that thread until it does, but not maxing out your CPU).  Which if there is you could do in your AsyncTask if it is helpful to still be in that model of execution for some other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it with a flag - it's not pretty though. I'm still interested in any ways to do this that are more elegant or correct. Or is this actually the right way to do it?

```
 private void login(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Doing login task...");
    isLoginFinished= false;
    ListenableFuture<JsonElement> result = mClient.invokeApi("login", mJSONHelper.makeLoginObject(thisUser));
    Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
            error.setError(ErrorHelper.Error.NETWORK_ERROR);
            isLoginFinished= true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JsonElement result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Login call was successful, parsing result:" + result.toString());
            isLoginFinished= true;
        }
    });
    while(!isLoginFinished); 
}
```

Comment: That will keep one of your processor cores at 100% until the network call completes as it is sitting in a tight loop.